# How to perform an action after button click

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener

I need to perform an action after *onClick* method of *OnClickListener* has run.

Here is my code for *onClickListener*:

```
    View.OnClickListener imgButton0Handler0 = new View.OnClickListener() {
    int identifier=0;

    public void onClick(View v) {

        //check if tile is found and return if it is
        if(isFound[identifier]==true)   return;
        //set tile as open
        checkField[identifier]=1;

        //set background on predetermined
        button0.setBackgroundResource(tiles[identifier]);
        }
};
```

After this has run, and the background is set I would like to call a method *checker(int identifier)* which will check for other open tiles and change backgrounds accordingly.

This method needs to be run separately because the background is only displayed after *onClick* finishes, and I need predetermined background shown for a short time before *checker* method changes it to something else.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have You Tried Post Delayed see this,

```
View.OnClickListener imgButton0Handler0 = new View.OnClickListener() {
        int identifier=0;

        public void onClick(View v) {

            //check if tile is found and return if it is
            if(isFound[identifier]==true)   return;
            //set tile as open
            checkField[identifier]=1;

            //set background on predetermined
            button0.setBackgroundResource(tiles[identifier]);

             new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // This method will be executed once the timer is over
                        // Start your app main activity
                        checker(identifier)  // your method call
                    }
                }, 3000); // 3 second
            }
    };
```